# Swipe direction when designing for Right-To-Left languages?

Tags: touch-screen, gestures, swipe, rtl

Books printed for people that reads Right-To-Left (RTL) languages is bound for flipping pages opposite direction of LTR.

1. What is todays common swipe direction when moving forward to next page/view, when designing for RTL in a touch screen context?
2. What would be the best direction?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to arabic speaking countries in the middle eastern region. While most commonly left to right is the swipe direction, It would need to be in reverse in this case, i.e. swiping right to left, just as the way they read from right to left as well as books also start at the opposite end compared to western books.

Comment: Thanks! I fully agree with you. Would love to see some studies or answers from a native arabic speaking person.